# How to make values of eeach of several factor levels into columns

Tags: r

I am a newbie with R. I have a large dataset (66M obs) with pixel temperature data of 4 water bodies (REF,LMB, OTH, FP) at hourly time steps (6am,7am,8am...), with several NA values illustrating blank pixels. I want to calculate stats and indexes for each water body and time step, and I find it difficult with my current structure.

My dataframe has 3 variables: time, water, temperature. I want to have it structured as several columns representing every water body-time combination. Can you help?

I have tried `mtabulate (qdapTools)`, but it does not work (and also it would only tabulate the water variable, and I want the combination of water and time)

```
DF_tab <- cbind(DF, mtabulate(DF$water))
```

Comment: post some sample data.... first read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6356278

Comment: It seems like you already have your dataset formatted as [Tidy Data](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html), but you're looking to spread it out into more columns.  You can do a lot of statistical analysis more easily with the Tidy Data already, but to spread out the data, you can look to using `tidyr::spread()` or `tidyr::pivot_wider()`.  [More informatinon here](http://statseducation.com/Introduction-to-R/modules/tidy%20data/spread/) and [here](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html).